# How to get my footer text vertically centered?

Tags: html, css, footer

```css
footer {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #464646;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  &copy; Name
</footer>
```

I want my name to be in the exact center of the footer. But it will only center at the top. Can someone answer this very basic question? Try to not make your answer to difficult as I am only a beginner.

Comment: Add `margin: 0 auto` to your styling.

Answer (score 2):

Before asking something, please check on internet if your question has any answer. You can vertical align by a lot of way.

Another person here answer by telling you to do it with line-height.DO NOT set a line-height to align center. It's a very bad practice. Because if for some reason your text goes to the line, everything will be break.

**Try to make things that will works in almost any case.**

However, here an example with display: flex;

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #464646;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<footer>
       <span>&copy; Name </span>
</footer>
```

Comment: http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way would be to set the `line-height` of the footer to the same value as the `height`, like below:

```css
footer {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #464646;
  line-height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  &copy; some Name
</footer>
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. It's not "bad" per se, its just quick and easy, as I said. If you want to have multiple lines or a more complex footer, I would not recommend it, too. But für horizontal centering of basic stuff it is an option. Especially if you look at the bunch of compatibility issues with flexbox solutions in IE11, which at least I still have to support :(